# Pandas/ Python list values of one column based on string value of another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a .csv file like this:

| Receipt ID | Name | Quantity | Category Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 135135 | Croissant | 1.0 | Food |
| 135135 | Cappucino | 1.0 | Drink |
| 143143 | Salad | 1.0 | Food |
| 154134 | Americano | 1.0 | Drink |
| 178781 | Cappucino | 1.0 | Drink |
| 169071 | Muffin | 1.0 | Food |
| 169071 | Latte | 1.0 | Drink |
| 169071 | Brownie | 1.0 | Food |

I want to get the `Receipt ID`s where the `Category Type` is "Food".

I've tried a few methods but none of them work.  For example,

```py
df1 = df.query('Category Type == Food')['Receipt ID'].unique()
```

I've also tried setting `Category Type` as index:

```py
df1 = df.set_index('Category Type').eq('Food')
print (df1.index[df1['Receipt ID']].tolist())
```

which gave me an empty list.

The `Receipt ID`s are not necessarily unique, although I want the outputs to be unique, and the final goal is to find the `Receipt ID` that contains both "Food" and "Drink". Could any expert please give me some help? Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

```
df.where(df['Category Type'] == 'Food')['Receipt ID'].dropna().values.tolist()
```

if you want unique:

```
df.where(df['Category Type'] == 'Food')['Receipt ID'].dropna().unique().astype(int).tolist()
```

or

```
df.loc[df['Category Type'] == 'Food', 'Receipt ID'].unique().tolist()
```

for all types:

```
df.groupby('Category Type').agg({'Receipt ID': 'unique'}).to_dict()
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data_str = """
Receipt ID  Name    Quantity    Category Type
135135  Croissant   1.0 Food
135135  Cappucino   1.0 Drink
143143  Salad   1.0 Food
154134  Americano   1.0 Drink
178781  Cappucino   1.0 Drink
169071  Muffin  1.0 Food
169071  Latte   1.0 Drink
169071  Brownie 1.0 Food
"""
# This is myself organizing the data, you can skip it here
io_str = StringIO(data_str)
df = pd.read_csv(io_str, header=0, sep='\t')

# start here
# method 1 
filter_df = df[df['Category Type'] == 'Food']
unique_list = filter_df['Receipt ID'].unique().tolist()
print(unique_list)

# method 2 use loc function
unique_list=df.loc[df['Category Type'] == 'Food', 'Receipt ID'].unique().tolist()
print(unique_list)
"""
[135135, 143143, 169071]
"""
```

Comment: Thank you! I never used StringIO before and am looking it up now

Comment: You can ignore it and deal with your own concerns first

Answer (score 0):

```
cond = df['Category Type'] == 'Food'
df[cond]['Receipt ID'].unique().tolist()
```